# How to remain on a page after submitting a form using PHP and update it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm struggling to find an answer to my question..

The website I'm creating contains a form in which users can enter Name and Email which is then forwarded using PHP to my email address (working).

Once the form is submitted the email is sent but currently I am redirected to the PHP file. I'm wondering how to remain on the same page and then update the sign up button text to "submitted".

This is the code so far..

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = "myemailaddress@test.com";
$email_subject = "New Subscriber";

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message = "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$name."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

}?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="send_form_email.php" method="post">
    <input placeholder="Name" type="text" name="name" class="name">
    <input placeholder="Email address" type="text" name="email" class="email">
    <button type="submit" class="sign-up" value="Press here" id="test">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Search on Google about `AJAX` or include the `send_form_email.php` file in index.php using `include` or `require` and set the form action to empty string

Comment: Ajax is the solution of all you problem

Comment: You have too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Comment: Ajax will cause him nothing but more problems if this is where he is currently stuck.

Answer (score 0):

After you have completed the action in send_form_email.php, do this:

header('Location: index.php');

Your code would look like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = "myemailaddress@test.com";
$email_subject = "New Subscriber";

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message = "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$name."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
header('Location: index.php');
}?>
```

Replace index.php with your original page name.